# Удалить записи дубликатов первой таблицы из второй таблицы

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Имею SQL Server 2014, 2 таблицы "doubles","export_table", в обеих таблицах могут быть дубликаты записей, одинаковая структура полей: "code","inn".

Мне нужно следующее:

1. Для каждого значения поля "inn" таблицы "doubles" найти дубликаты в этой таблице и взять их значения поля "code" той же таблицы.
2. Для каждого значения взятого поля "code" найти есть ли такие значения в таблице "export_table".
3. Если таких нет, то удалить все записи из таблицы "export_table" для данных кодов.
4. Данные 3 действия для каждой группы дубликатов инн из первой таблицы.

```sql
SELECT count([t1].inn) as r1,
       t1.inn as tinn,
       count([t2].inn) as r2,
       t2.inn as t2inn
FROM [export_table] as t1 
right join  doubles as t2 on t1.inn=t2.inn 
where t1.tinn is null 
group by t1.inn,t2.inn  
order by t2inn asc
```

Comment: Что-то тяжело у Вас с объяснением. Попробуйте создать fiddle с тест-наполнением и показать требуемый на таких данных результат.

Comment: Что это такое? Вот может проще будет. Мне нужно удалить из таблицы "export_table" все записи по значениям поля "code", условие в таблице "export_table" не все значения code дубликатов ИНН из таблицы "doubles". Проверка должна быть для каждой группы.

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что дубликат вы определяете как запись, имеющую такой же `inn`, что и другая запись в этой же таблице? При этом дубликаты могут иметь разный `code`?

Comment: Условие 3 выглядит противоречащим себе. "Если записей с заданным кодом нет, удалить все такие записи." Нет ли здесь ошибки? Кроме того, в п.4 вы таблицы по `inn` соединяете, а в текстовом описании соединяете по `code`

Comment: *Что это такое?* https://dbfiddle.uk/ Выбираете свою СУБД и версию, и копируете запросы на создание и наполнение таблиц. Запускаете, убеждаетесь, что выполняется без ошибок, в т.ч. и SELECT из заполненной таблицы. И публикуете полученный адрес.

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin под дубликатом понимаю совпадение по полю ИНН разных записей таблицы, в обеих таблицах могут быть совпадения по ИНН, в таблице doubles для одного ИНН разные коды и в таблице export_table также. Вы правильно увидели ошибку. Нужно удалить записи из export_table где нет хоть одного кода из группы дубликатов по ИНН таблицы doubles. Может теперь понятнее стало.

Comment: @Akina дополнил картинкой и комментарием, может теперь понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
DELETE FROM export
FROM export
INNER JOIN doubles d ON export.inn=d.inn
LEFT JOIN export e ON d.code=e.code AND d.inn=e.inn
WHERE e.code IS NULL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=5c75d182ccd7d60f4ee1b40dac3d9cb9)

Правда, я типы полей и значения упростил (Вы так и не создали fiddle с правдоподобными тестовыми данными), но соответствие соблюл. Впрочем, это не должно влиять на результат.

Если в `export` возможны значения `inn`, отсутствующие в `doubles`, для их удаления заменить `INNER JOIN` на `LEFT JOIN` - добавьте в fiddle в `export` значение `(7,4)`.

Comment: спасибо это именно то что было нужно, только можно вас попросить объяснить данный скрипт с точки зрения логики.